# Flutter exception Builder keeps being called

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a flutter Image.file() to show an Image in my app. I am also using the errorBuilder to handle any crashes and show a message to the user.

I encounter a problem when i do these steps.

1. Load a good image that works
2. Load a corrupt image into the same Image.File() widget
3. Load the original good image back into the same Image.File() widget

It seems every file change after the corrupt photo is passed in (step 2) will result in the error builder being shown and not the new good image.

If i don't pass in the corrupt photo in step 2, the photo changes like it should. Is this a bug with the flutter Image() or should I be doing something after it goes into the errorBuilder.

Here is my current setup.

```
Image.file(
        file,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          print("Failed to initialise the file");
          print(stackTrace);
          //  Once an error occurs it always goes in here 
          return Text("an error occurred");
        },
      );
```

The actual error I receive on all file changes when/after the corrupt file is passed in is

```
Could not instantiate image codec.
```

---

UPDATE

I have wrote a dartpad that shows the problem i am experiencing.

https://dartpad.dev/98c2dacb481c088dfd2e5bee490f45ed

If you click

1. Good Image
2. Good Image 2
3. Good Image
4. Good Image 2

The images cycle correctly... which works.

if you then click "Corrupt Image" which will attempt to load a corrupt jpeg file the error builder will fire.

If you then click "Good Image" or "Good Image 2" they no longer build and the Image is stuck loading the error builder everytime... How can I get it to then load one of the good images again?

Please let me know if I haven't been clear and I will add more information :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't see the whole picture, but isn't it because your component's build is being called multiple times?

Comment: But when I load the third image in (which is a good file) It should not go in the error builder and should display an image

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue. it works when I put three image.file in Column, could you post how do you use this code snippet? It might be related to tree and key issue. need to reproduce.

Comment: @chunhunghan  I have added an example dart pad and some instructions in my answer.. sorry i wasnt clear enough in the first question. Thanks a lot for responding so quickly

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
This error can be fixed with add `key: UniqueKey()`, 
I have test it with DardPad works fine 
code snippet

```
Image.network(
          _selectedImageURL,
          key: UniqueKey(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _goodImageOne =
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/June_odd-eyed-cat_cropped.jpg";
  String _corruptImage =
      "https://srv-file16.gofile.io/download/hwTzLI/cat_corrupt.jpg";
  String _goodImageTwo =
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Tabby_cat_with_blue_eyes-3336579.jpg";

  String _selectedImageURL;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedImageURL = _goodImageOne;
  }

  void _changeFile(String newUrl) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedImageURL = newUrl;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              _selectedImageURL,
              key: UniqueKey(),
              height: 300,
              width: 200,
              loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                  ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                      ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                      : null,
                ));
              },
              errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                  StackTrace stackTrace) {
                return Text("Cannot display url");
              },
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _changeFile(_goodImageOne),
              child: Text("Good Image"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _changeFile(_corruptImage),
              child: Text("Corrupt Image"),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _changeFile(_goodImageTwo),
              child: Text("Good Image 2"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```